# FTP Problems on v18.04 with vsftpd and Google Cloud Platform

Tags: server, 18.04, ftp, vsftpd

I'm having some unexplainable issues trying to setup FTP on vsftpd with my Google Cloud Platform compute engine. I've been messing with a bunch of different settings to get this going, but one issue keeps popping up.

In FileZilla, I get an error saying "Failed to retrieve directory listing." Does anyone know a good fix? Let me know what logs etc. you need from me.

I've tried this on fresh installs plenty of times with no luck. The ports are all set through the firewall as well.

Thank you so much!